# Retrieve RGBA from a single object at cursor position

Tags: javascript, svg, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have a fabricjs canvas with multiple SVG objects which may or may not overlap.

Some of the SVG objects have transparent areas, such that the transparent area of Object A may be positioned on top of a filled area of Object B, as in the diagram below:

[image: Object Overlap Illustration]

In the above diagram, the black border illustrates the SVG Object's bounding box.

Points X & Y illustrate cursor locations during object selection.

I am interested in retrieving the RGBA value at the cursor position, such that the selected object is taken into account.

If the user clicks at either Point X or Point Y, then the selected object (with normal behaviour of fabricjs) is Object A, as Object A is the topmost object and the user has clicked within the bounding box.

What I want to do is retrieve the RGBA value (or just the alpha value will do) of Object A *at the cursor position* i.e. at both Point X and Point Y, Object A is transparent.

From what I can gather from the fabricjs documentation - I can only see a way to get the RGBA value at a cursor position from the canvas as a whole - not for specific objects. This means that Point X is a transparent value, whilst Point Y is blue with full opacity.

```
var pixelData = this.canvas.getContext().getImageData(pointer.x, pointer.y, 1, 1).data;
```

What I'm looking for is a way to query the pixel data for a single object at a specific cursor location, perhaps something like:

```
var pixelData = selectedObject.getImageData(pointer.x, pointer.y, 1, 1).data;
```

I understand that fabricjs may not directly support such a feature, but I'm wondering whether anybody has a nice way of achieving this so that I can accurately determine when the user has clicked on a *transparent area* of an object.

I'm supposing that as I'm using SVG images, the solution may have something to do with figuring out the cursor position in relation to the SVG paths and determining whether the user has clicked on a filled section of the SVG, but I'm just a bit stuck with working out the best way to tackle the problem so I'm really open to any suggestions!

If anybody has any pointers it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: Convert the SVG to a canvas image and then read the colour off the canvas.

Comment: Hi @RobertLongson - thanks for the suggestion. I believe this is ultimately the only way to do this - I'm having a play around still but I expect this is probably the best shot.